# How to tweak webpack config when working with vue-cli?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs3, vue-cli

There is the following project structure: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Question:
Is it possible with this structure to customize Webpack configuration? 
If so, how can this task be achieved?

In other words: 
Where should you look for the next file (or settings)?
[image]